in android studio, i have a problem with jdk 22 & 21 & gradle 8.5 & 8.7
snippet of how i got the problem
if you look in the image above, it's asking me to upgrade to jdk 21+, to solve that error.
But if i do it as could be seen in the next imagesnippet of build>gradle
it still shows me the same error message asking me to upgrade to jdk 21+ which i already did,
in another instance it's giving me error something like in this below question.
Gradle 8.7 cannot find installed JDK 22 in IntelliJ
please help, thanks in advance.
coding in android studio, trying to create a count button in first fragment that would update the count number in the first fragment screen. couldn't get it right.

Do not upgrade to JDK 22 unless you have a very specific version to pick that. Switch to JDK 21 instead. 21 is a LTS release (meaning long-term-support) and way more likely to be supported by various tools. So unless you know that you need a feature from JDK 22 that's not available in 21, avoid 22. Specifically (as the linked-to answer already tells you!) Gradle 8.7 can NOT run in JDK 22.

https://developer.android.com/build/jdks   , find out : (1) Android 14 (API 34) -> JDK 17
(2) Android 13 (API 33) -> JDK 11
(3)  Android 12 (API 32) -> JDK 11

But even if upgrade to JDK 22, it is still showing the same error asking me to upgrade to jdk 21+. you have any other way to fix that error?

Your first image is no help at all. Please follow site rules and post in text the error you are getting.

But even if upgrade to JDK 22, it is still showing the same error asking me to upgrade to jdk 21+ what is it? Please edit your question and show that error message and describe how you got it.

I edited the question, please take a look and let me know if you guys understand or if I should input more.

Your code seems wrong, but you didn't post it as text, so it won't be seen as much as necessary. Do you have a field definition outside of a class? You seem to have an import statement and then immediately switch to defining a TextView, but that isn't inside a class, which doesn't work in Java. You need to define a class and put the field inside of it. The only reason it suggests to "update to JDK 21" is because the JDK thinks you're trying to use some other feature, but I think your code is just wrong.
